# How to make the bot send personalized emojis?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Well, I'm currently using the emoji **:x:**, but on my server I have an emoji called **:superbotxemoji**: I just don't know how I get my bot to use it

My code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
 name: 'say',
 description: 'say',
 execute(message, args) {
  const { prefix, token } = require('../config.json');

  if (!message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR'))
   return message.channel.send({
    embed: {
     color: 16777201,
     description: `:x: | ${message.author}, You are not allowed to use this command.`,
     footer: {
      text: `   | Required permission: ADMINISTRATOR`,
     },
    },
   });

  if (!args.length)
   return message.channel.send({
    embed: {
     color: 16777201,
     description: `:x: | ${message.author}, You need to put a message.`,
     footer: {
      text: `   | Example: !say hello`,
     },
    },
   });

  const sayMessage = args.join(' ');
  message.delete({ timeout: 1 });
  message.channel.send(sayMessage);
 },
};
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is actually a very detailed explanation from the official `discord.js` guide which you can find [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#unicode-emojis), although I'll try to paraphrase it.

To send a custom emoji, you must get that emoji's unique `ID`. To find that, you must send the emote in discord with a backslash in front of it; essentially escaping the emoji.

[image: Escape]

This will result in the emojis unique `ID` in this format: `<:emoji-name:emoji-id>`

[image: Format]

If you paste this special string into a message, the bot will send the emoji. However, the emoji must be from a guild the bot is part of.

[image: Emoji]

On the other hand, there's another very easy way to get an emoji using the [`client.emojis.cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildEmojiManager?scrollTo=cache) collection and the [`.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) method.

```js
client.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === '<name of emoji>')
```

[image: .find()]

This method will also make it possible to send custom emojis, however, this time you can find them by name. Be careful, if there are more than one emojis by the given name, it will not work.

A way to bypass this problem would be looking at a `guild.emojis.cache` collection. This way the amount of possible duplicate emojis would be narrowed down.